# isdn s/t vs ethernet vs adsloisdn

Tags: cisco, router, ethernet

On the back of my cisco router, I see the following ports:

- 4 LAN ports
- ISDN S/T
- ADSLoISDN
- Console

Two really basic questions:

1) Is the ISDN S/T port like any other WAN ethernet port? (i.e. can I plug an ethernet cable from my existing cable modem into it? or do I need a different router?)

2) To configure the router, am I able to connect to it via a LAN port (like other routers) or do I have to connect via the Console port?

Thanks.

Comment: Knowing the model is the most important part of getting the help you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) No, ISDN and Ethernet are totally different, even if the ports have the same size.

2) You don't even tell us the model of the device.

Comment: Depending on the model, Cisco's "console" port is most likely also not ethernet, it's a serial port you'll need an adapter to plug a serial cable into.